# Kafka Receiver is unable to consume messages from a topic after Kafka is restarted

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-webflux, kafka-consumer-api, reactor-kafka

Initially, the Kafka receiver worked as expected but once the Kafka broker restarts and comes back, the same receiver is unable to receive messages and there's no error seen in the logs except warn

```
    ReceiverOptions<String, byte[]> receiverConfig = getReceiverConfig(topic);
    pipelineStatusKafkaReceiver = KafkaReceiver.create(
        receiverConfig.subscription(Collections.singleton(topic)));
    pipelineStatusKafkaReceiver.receive()
        .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(300, Duration.of(10L, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)))
        .doOnError(throwable -> LOGGER.error("Error from retry"))
        .subscribe(
            receiverRecord -> Mono.just("Kafka: Listening Pipeline status on {}")
                .doOnEach(logOnNext(s -> LOGGER.info(s, topic)))
                .flatMap(s -> updatePipelineStatus(receiverRecord))
                .doOnSuccess(receiveRecord -> `receiverRecord.receiverOffset().acknowledge())`
                .subscribe());
```

Answer (score 2):

This implementation will call `subscribeAndRetryOnError` recursively when an error occurs, effectively restarting the subscription upon disconnection. The `Disposable` will help manage the subscription lifecycle to prevent resource leaks.

```
private Disposable disposable;

public void subscribeAndUpdatePipelineStatues(String topic) {
    ReceiverOptions<String, byte[]> receiverConfig = getReceiverConfig(topic);
    pipelineStatusKafkaReceiver = KafkaReceiver.create(receiverConfig.subscription(Collections.singleton(topic)));
    disposable = subscribeAndRetryOnError(topic);
}

private Disposable subscribeAndRetryOnError(String topic) {
    return pipelineStatusKafkaReceiver.receive()
        .concatMap(receiverRecord ->
            Mono.just("Kafka: Listening Pipeline status on {}")
                .doOnNext(s -> LOGGER.info(s, topic))
                .then(updatePipelineStatus(receiverRecord))
                .doOnSuccess(v -> receiverRecord.receiverOffset().acknowledge())
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                    LOGGER.error("Error processing record", throwable);
                    return Mono.empty();
                })
        )
        .doOnError(throwable -> {
            LOGGER.error("Receiver terminated with error, restarting...", throwable);
            disposable.dispose();
            disposable = subscribeAndRetryOnError(topic);
        })
        .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me, I am using 1.3.10 version

Comment: It seems I provided the incorrect solution. Based on the code snippet and the version 1.3.10, I assume you are using the reactive-kafka library (also known as reactor-kafka)

Comment: Updated my answer try again.

Comment: Thanks, still I am facing issues after trying the latest change. Looks like the receiver gets terminated once I restart kafka

Comment: let's try another approach by wrapping the entire subscription inside a method that can be called recursively upon disconnection from the Kafka broker. I will update code.

Comment: Thanks. We need to dispose the subscription once Kafka is reconnected. The issue is it'll never throw an error and doOnError will not get executed. We added a workaround where we check if Kafka is up using the KafkaAdminClient library and whenever Kafka is restarted, we would dispose the subscription and subscribe again once all the Kafka nodes are up.